# How can I move the map to a specified location using here.com javascript api

Tags: javascript, here-api

Is there a function that moves (centers) the map at a specific coordinate? I'm building an application in which, granted an event, the map should center at a specific object in the map.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You need to attempt this, post the code you try, and any problems you are having so that we may help you with said issues. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your question.

Comment: The very first example of the [JS API Explorer](https://developer.here.com/api-explorer) covers that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes
The ***map.setCenter()*** method and ***map.setZoom()*** method are able to control the location of the map.

an exaple may be:

```js
/**
 * Moves the map to display over Berlin
 *
 * @param  {H.Map} map      A HERE Map instance within the application
 */
function moveMapToBerlin(map) {
  map.setCenter({
    lat: 52.5159,
    lng: 13.3777
  });
  map.setZoom(14);
}
```

where map is the map you whant to move.